# How to return multiple column values for setValue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Am trying to run a bit of script to find various cell values, return each of the column numbers of the cells that contain the searched-for values, and then `setValue` according to each return. I've got as far as the below example:

```
function superAuto() {
  var report = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REPORTSHEET');
  var reportData = report.getDataRange().getValues();

  var scorecard = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SCORESHEET');
var scorecardData = scorecard.getDataRange().getValues();

var column = columnfinder ();

scorecard.getRange(18, [column]).setValue("Example input");
}


function columnfinder() {
  var report = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REPORTSHEET');
  var reportData = report.getDataRange().getValues();

    for(var j=0, jLen=reportData.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      for(var k=0, kLen=reportData[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        var find = "Nov-20" || "Dec-20" || "Jan-21";
        if(find == reportData[j][k]) {
          Logger.log(k);
          return (k);}
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem with my code as it stands is that it only returns `k` for one of the search terms (the first one, `"Nov-20"`), and therefore only `setValue`'s one cell in `SCORESHEET` based on that, whereas as by this example I'd really like 3 cells to be found in `REPORTSHEET` (all the search terms are there to be found), 3 values of `k` to be returned, and therefore 3 cells to be populated in `SCORESHEET`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `columnfinder()` to return a list of column indexes, you need to define an array variable that will hold the matched column indexes before returning its value. You can use [array.push()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp) to append values to your array.

### Your code:

```
function superAuto() {
  var report = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REPORTSHEET');
  var reportData = report.getDataRange().getValues();

  var scorecard = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SCORESHEET');
  var scorecardSheet = scorecard.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var scorecardData = scorecard.getDataRange().getValues();

  var columns = columnfinder();
  Logger.log(columns);

  columns.forEach(col=>{
    scorecardSheet.getRange(18, col).setValue("Example input");
  })

}


function columnfinder() {
  var report = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REPORTSHEET');
  var reportData = report.getDataRange().getValues();
  var result = [];

  for(var j=0, jLen=reportData.length; j<jLen; j++) {
    for(var k=0, kLen=reportData[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
      var find = ["Nov-20", "Dec-20", "Jan-21"];

      if(find.includes(reportData[j][k])) {
        //return (k);

        //Array is in zero-based, but column index for sheet range is in one-based.
        result.push(k+1);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

---

### Modifications Done:

1. I declared a `result` array in `columnfinder()` that will hold column indexes and push found indexes using in `result.push(k+1);`
2. Replaced the condition in matching strings in `columnfinder()`, I declared an array `find` and used [array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and check if `find` array contains the current cell being checked.
3. Return the `result` after finishing the loop in `columnfinder()`
4. Added a `scorecardSheet` variable in `superAuto()`. Initially you are trying to use `getRange(row, column)` in the spreadsheet `scorecard` which is not possible. (*See [Spreadsheet methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)*). [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) is available in [Sheet Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

---

### Output:

Report Sheet:

[image]

Score Sheet:

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, thanks so much for this, it works perfectly. I wondered if I might bring your attention to another question I have?

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65849476/running-script-for-multiple-search-terms-found-on-different-sheet

I think your answer to this question will somehow apply there, but I've not been able to apply it in the right way.