# Running script for multiple search terms found on different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get a `SCORESHEET` to populate from a `REPORTSHEET`, using a `REFERENCESHEET` to collate search terms and destination cells.

The script I'm running is as below. The idea is that the script finds `searchDate`'s in the `REFERENCESHEET` and uses them to locate data columns in the `REPORTSHEET`:

```
function superAuto() {
  var report = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REPORTSHEET');
  var reportData = report.getDataRange().getValues();

  var reference = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REFERENCESHEET');
  var referenceData = reference.getDataRange().getValues();

  var scorecard = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SCORESHEET');
  var scorecardData = scorecard.getDataRange().getValues();

  var tExpenses = "Total Expenses";

  for(n=0;n<referenceData.length;++n){
    var searchDate = referenceData[n][0] ;
    Logger.log (searchDate)
  }

  var column = columnfinder(searchDate);

  for (var a = 0; a < referenceData.length; a++) {
    var refRow = referenceData[a];
   for (var i = 0; i < reportData.length; i++) {
    var row = reportData[i];
    if (row[0] == tExpenses && refRow[0] == searchDate) {
      scorecard.getRange(refRow[5]).setValue(row[column]);
    }
   }
  }
}

function columnfinder(find) {
  var report = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REPORTSHEET');
  var reportData = report.getDataRange().getValues();

  var reference = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REFERENCESHEET');
  var referenceData = reference.getDataRange().getValues();

  
    for(var j=0, jLen=reportData.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      for(var k=0, kLen=reportData[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        if(find == reportData[j][k]) {
          Logger.log(k);
          return (k);}
      }
    }
  }
```

Broadly speaking, the code works, as if I define `searchDate` as one of the terms I'm looking for (e.g. Jan-21) it all works fine. The issue is that it doesn't seem to be doing so when finding multiple search terms - and therefore populating multiple rows - as per:

```
for(n=0;n<referenceData.length;++n){
    var searchDate = referenceData[n][0] ;
    Logger.log (searchDate)
  }
```

The log tells me that it's finding `searchDate`'s in the REFERENCESHEET, but it's not able to run them through `function columnfinder` (I get no logs for the second logger).

I suspect the answer lay somewhere in an earlier great answer I received to an earlier version of this idea - [How to return multiple column values for setValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65847172/how-to-return-multiple-column-values-for-setvalue/65848230#65848230) - but I've not been able to make it fit. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Please find a sample REFERENCESHEET & REPORTSHEET for more info:

[image: referencesheet]
[image: reportsheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The log tells me that it's finding searchDate's in the REFERENCESHEET,
> but it's not able to run them through function columnfinder (I get no
> logs for the second logger)

You **don't** execute `columnfinder` inside the `for` loop.

Try this:

```
for(n=0;n<referenceData.length;++n){
    var searchDate = referenceData[n][0] ;
    Logger.log(searchDate);
    columnfinder(searchDate); // modified code
  }
```

and you will get both `logs`.

Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: This actually answers his issue mentioned on the post, although what I'm worrying is that the whole bigger picture. I'm not sure if this is all the answer he needs, but since it was accepted, I guess I was just overthinking the issue he encountered. Kudos. Might have to follow this post as OP might have additional questions as I see that OP's code seems so focused on single searches yet he wants multiple search terms as his goal.

Comment: @NaziA you might be right, but Marios' answer works for me. I will apply your solution when I have some time, as I think there's some good learning in there.

Comment: @NaziA your answers is a good addition :)

Comment: @ChristopherBirks, if you encounter some issues, don't hesitate to comment on my answer below so I'll be notified. I'll be glad to assist you

Comment: Thanks for that @Marios. I appreciate it. I definitely overthink sometimes and did an overhaul with the code based on his end goal. Although that might not be needed as of now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use have it assigned to `array` since you are returning possible multiple columns/dates:

```
function superAuto() {
  var report = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REPORTSHEET');
  var reportData = report.getDataRange().getValues();

  var reference = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REFERENCESHEET');
  var referenceData = reference.getDataRange().getValues();

  var scorecard = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SCORESHEET');
  var scorecardData = scorecard.getDataRange().getValues();

  var tExpenses = "Total Expenses";

  var searchDates = [];

  for (n = 0; n < referenceData.length; ++n) {
    searchDates.push(referenceData[n][0])
  }

  var columns = columnfinder(searchDates);

  columns.forEach(function (column, index) {
    referenceData.forEach(function (refRow) {
      reportData.forEach(function (row) {
        if (row[0] == tExpenses && refRow[0] == searchDates[index]) {
          scorecard.getRange(refRow[5].toString()).setValue(row[column]);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}

function columnfinder(dates) {
  var report = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REPORTSHEET');
  var reportData = report.getDataRange().getValues();

  var reference = SpreadsheetApp.openById('REFERENCESHEET');
  var referenceData = reference.getDataRange().getValues();

  var columns = [];

  dates.forEach(function (date) {
    reportData.forEach(function (row, i) {
      row.forEach(function (col, i) {
        if (date == reportData[i][j]) {
          columns.push(reportData[i][j]);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  return columns;
}
```

I changed some variables into proper variable names to avoid confusion.

Additionally, if it doesn't work, you might need to share a proper visualization of the data, or better yet, provide some sample sheet we can work on for us to be able to give you a better and tested answer.

Comment: Forgot to support the solution.

Comment: I appreciate it @Marios.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Marios, that's twice in a week. Much appreciated.

Slight adaptation, in order for it to populate `SCORECARD` I needed to bring everything into the `for` loop, as below:

```
 for(n=0;n<referenceData.length;++n){
    var searchDate = referenceData[n][0] ;
    Logger.log (searchDate)
    var column = columnfinder(searchDate);

  for (var a = 0; a < referenceData.length; a++) {
    var refRow = referenceData[a];

   for (var i = 0; i < reportData.length; i++) {
    var row = reportData[i];
    if (row[0] == tExpenses && refRow[0] == searchDate) {
      scorecard.getRange(refRow[5]).setValue(row[column]);
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Glad it was helpful